# How to shuffle the contents of a text file in groups of n lines in Python

Tags: python, file

Let's say the text file is this:

```
1
2
3
4
5 
6
...
```

What I want is to randomely order the contents in groups of N lines, without shuffling the lines in each group, like this:

```
#In this case, N = 2.
5
6
1
2
7
8
...
```

My file isn't huge, it will be less than 50 lines for sure.

I've tried to do this using this code:

```
import random


with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = []
    groups = []
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line[:-1])
        if len(lines) > 3:
            groups.append(lines)


            lines = []

    random.shuffle(groups)


with open("data.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(groups))
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PYTHON/python/Data.py", line 19, in <module>
    file.write("\n".join(groups))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to join a list of lists; flatten them first:

```
with open("data.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(['\n'.join(g) for g in groups]))
```

You could use any of the [recommended methods of chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) to produce your groups. With a `file` object, all you need to do is `zip()` the file with itself:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    groups = list(zip(file, file))
```

Note that this'll drop the last line if there are an odd number of lines in the file. This includes the newlines now, so join on `''` rather than `'\n'`.

You could also join the two lines for each group together before shuffling:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    groups = [a + b for a, b in zip(file, file)]

random.shuffle(groups)

with open("data.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("".join(groups))
```

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any way to only open the file once?

Comment: @user1236969: sure: [Delete the contents of a file before writing to it (in Python)?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41915140); open in `'r+'` mode, read, rewind, truncate, then write.